# How to measure WCF outbound connection count?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, performancecounter

I have a wcf webservice and 5 client machines which connect to it remotely.

Unfortunately, I'm experiencing some communication errors on my client machines (Its a 3 tier application).

I would like to measure the number of outbound connection on each client machine and write it in the logs to check whether the communication errors have anything to do with concurrent connection limits / number.

How can i do it in code?

I know i have access to performance counters values but i couldn't figure out which performance counter i need to measure.

two more things:

1. Each client is installed on a separate machine.
2. I set the maxconnections property in config like this -

   ```
   <system.net>
     <connectionManagement>
       <add address="*" maxconnection="65535"/>
     </connectionManagement>
   </system.net>
   ```

Comment: are those 5 clients on the same machine? WCF has a default concurrent connections count from the same machine of 2

Comment: clients are on different machines. each machine has a single client installed but there are many threads in the app which make concurrent calls. as for the limit of 2 connections please see edit.

Comment: so you want to count the number connections from each client on server side or client side?

Comment: can you deploy performance counters using perfmon on the client, i think there are options there to let you figure out the number of connections being open.

Comment: I also feel the connection errors you are facing could be because of faulted connections? It needs to be handled properly like if you face a fault error then you need to abort.

Answer (score 0):

you can use signalr for this. use an interception/dispatcher for method invocations and push to some client(s) to connections state: opened or closed then count number of connections in real time.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean... could you please elaborate?